# Complex if condition

Tags: c++, logical-operators, operator-precedence

In a legacy code, I have encountered the following expression:

```
if (!m_bMsOcs && bChannelData || m_bMsOcs && !bStunType)
```

I guess the intended condition was

```
if ((!m_bMsOcs && bChannelData) || (m_bMsOcs && !bStunType))
```

I am not sure. How is the original conditional expression supposed to execute? Please help.

Comment: Those two expressions are equivalent. What is your problem with the first one? That it isn't parenthesized defensively? That it's not indented nicely?

Comment: i guess it would be faster to check it by yourself than create a new thread. There is even online compilator for c++. http://ideone.com/

Comment: The `&&` operator has higher precedence than `||`, so your guess is equivalent to the original expression.

Comment: @KilianFoth, I just could not understand it. I should have read about it before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of logical operators is:

```
! > && > ||
```

so your guess is correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( ((!m_bMsOcs) && bChannelData) || (m_bMsOcs && (!bStunType)) )
```

The operator precedence is `!` > `&&` > `||`

Answer (score 1):

This is an operator precedence question.  The parenthesis take precedence, followed by your logicals.  As && has greater priority than ||, you're correct in your guess.

Answer (score 1):

Logical `and` have higher precedence than `or`: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

So you are right about the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer is correct:)

If (this and that) or (this and that)

So if either of the ands  are correct it evaluates true

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the two expressions are equivalent because of C++ precedence rules.

Here's a truth table that might help make it clear what will happen (I agree that the conditional expression is more complex than I like, too):

```
m_bMsOcs    bChannelData    bStunType       Execute?
========    ============    =========       ========
    0             0             0
    0             0             1
    0             1             0               Y
    0             1             1               Y

    1             0             0               Y
    1             0             1
    1             1             0               Y
    1             1             1
```

Note that the `1` and `0` in the table just represent `true`/`false` values (i.e., the variables don't have to have a value of `1` - any non-zero value will be treated as a `1`).  I just find the table to be more readable using `0`/`1` instead of `T`/`F`.

Comment: Is that table created by application? Can you tell the name of that application?

Comment: @Michal: I created the table by hand.